# Why did my redis fill up so quickly?

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis, node-redis, nosql

I'm [using redis to store bits to track hourly, daily, weekly, and monthly active users](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hau). One bit is stored every time I have an event that has a unique `user`, `hour`, or `eventType`.

The redis command I'm using (node client) is **`client.setbit(key, id, 1);`**

Where `key` is something like `login-mobile-2015-11-14-04` and `id` is a six-digit integer (referring to the user).

Within just a few days, I hit the 25MB limit of the heroku redis free plan, but the maximum actual amount of data (based on number of unique events & users is `192000` per day, which is waaay fewer bytes than 25MB. I suspect that something about my keys being too long or something is the issue, but I don't really know much about redis so figured I'd just ask.

Comment: According to redis command, SETBIT create a string with the length that can hold the max offset value ever used (in your case user's id) and set that bit to either 0x00 or 0x01 (depends on you SETBIT to 0 or 1). In your case it means at most (999999 / 8) bytes + 26 bytes (key name) + redis overhead (???) used per day. I don't know how heroku calculates, I have a blank new redis and SETBIT key 0 1 > SETBIT key 999999 1 > SAVE results the dump.rdb size = 1484 bytes.

Comment: Ken, the RDB dump will always be significantly smaller than in-memory storage. Thwy are not comparable.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in Redis string internal data structure. Redus use [SDS](https://github.com/antirez/sds) strings and sometimes its real important to undestand how it works. The most omportant is memory allocation strategy in SDS.

Actually, it just simply doubles the original size when it is less than SDS_MAX_PREALLOC(1MB). This is similar to C++ vector allocation strategy when memory is not enough. This is why string append operation does not need to allocate memory every time.

Why this important for yout question. SETBIT just uses string as container, so with a six-digit integer as userId you have (in worst case) 999,999 / 8  = 125,000 bytes + 8 bytes overhead. But according to allocation strategy you may have up to 250,000 + 8 bytes overhead per key.

So some maths:

- Hourly stats is 250 kb * 24 per day = 6mb
- Daily, weekly and monthly is 250kb per each counter (1mb total)

So, in worst case you spend 25 mb just in 4 days. But ever in best case, then the 125 kb is a max key memory, you spend 25 mb in 7-8 days.

BITSET is fast and nice but consume much of memory. Using BITSET for daily, weekly and monthly data looks like a right decision if you have much of users online. Bitset is not the best choise for sparsed data.

Analize your hourly data - may be using SET allow to use less memory - your userId is integer (4 bytes) so 128kb is ~32,000 users per hour. Also look at 
[redis memory optimization guide](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools/wiki/Redis-Memory-Optimization) - you may find much of interesting about real memory usage in redis.

About SET workaround - is your hourly online less then ~32,000 users - SET is your choise.

Also you may debug your BITSET key with redis command `DEBUG SDSLEN <key name>`- it shows you allocated memory for SDS string under bitset data.

Comment: This is good, but there is also the possibility of too many clients. Each client connection takes additional memory for buffers which comes from the max memory setting in Redis,  Thus every additional client connection consumes some of the 25MB limit in this case.  For illustration if each connection took 128k of buffer space and there were 100 open connections nearly half the available memory is taken by clients. The third possibility is a slow client doing the same thing by keeping buffers full.

Comment: As i know from redis sources the connection pool do not consume 128 kb per connection. Redis is epool based and each connection consume just some kb per connection. Instead of key space memory the connection memory is not cached and free up after clien has been disconnected. So i do not think that this can one of real reasons of such behaviour as Malcolm ask. Can you tellmore about this or may be post some links about this?

Comment: The 128k is an example to drive the point not a declaration. And the amount they can consume is dependent on the buffer settings, the speed of the clients, and the speed of the network. Some client libraries don't properly close connections either or open up connections for every command. And finally, whether it is feed up after the spike is irrelevant to the state of the memory while the connection is open. Most client libraries properly leave the connection open. You need to look at the whole picture, not merely redis source.

Comment: Look like as offtopic. The question about concrete software - redis server. Redis uses epool/select as network backend. The last one is well documented and works predictably. Also the heroku cloud platform do not charged the linux system network buffer allocated memory so i don't understand why your comment. Sometimes you need to answer to a specific question in a particular situation, and not to come up with some hypothetical possibility.

Comment: Heroku has nothing to do with this. It isn't hypothetical it is something many people have seen and I've seen happen to many people. Whether you've personally seen it or understand it doesn't change the fact. The original question lacks enough information to make a proper determination - and is off topic for the entire site (it belongs on ServerFault). Your answer, while good, is incomplete. That is what I am referring to. You can choose to get better and improve the answer to cover the possible scenarios based on feedback by experts or you can refuse to, that is up to you. EoR.

Comment: You answered my question in abstract I guess, but it would be helpful to know if there's anything I can do (aside from reducing the userid integer size) to mitigate this? I can't afford gigabytes of redis just to store a few megabytes of data...

Comment: MalcolmOcean i updating my answer with possible workaround for your case.